# how to enable html editor in eclipse JUNO for phonegap application?

Tags: html, eclipse, cordova

I am using eclipse JUNO as **Android Developer Tools**, I am developing PhoneGap application, So I need **mobile html** but, It does not highlight the html syntax. So How to enable its **syntax highlighter and suggestions [image]for html syntax. **

Comment: Right click on file you want to edit > click **Open With** > click **HTML Editor**. Next time you open file it will open with this editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Every body I got my answer **[form this link](http://lizusefulstuff.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-add-html-editor-for-eclipse.html)**
I summarized it

In Eclipse Juno Go  ..

Step1:Help=>Install New Software..

Step2:Select the Juno repository (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/) from the 'Work with:' menu:

Step3:In the search box, enter 'web' to filter the results, and select 'Web Page Editor':

Step4: Click Next:

Step5: Accept the terms and click Finish:

Step7: You might see this - just click OK:

Step8: Click Yes when ready:

If color of html files is not change(only black) So you have to go

step9: Window => Preferences menu as shown:
Then for both *.htm and *.html,

Step10: click on the 'HTML Editor' in the window below and click the 'Default' and 'OK' to apply.

**Now open with HTML Editor**
Check the Eclipse editor for HTML

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse Juno by default has the html tags enabled.

Try File-> New -> file -> FileName.html -> Finish.Now try pasting your code in this file.

Use Ctrl + Space for suggestions.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply, But I am developing phonegap application, By default it is not enable,